# C++ declaring a const function in header and implementing it in .cpp

Tags: c++, constants, header-files, declaration

I have the following header:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum COLOR {Green, Blue, White, Black, Brown};


class Animal{
    private:
    string _name;
    COLOR _color;

    public:
    Animal();
    ~Animal();
    void speak() const;
    void move() const;
} ;
```

And the following .cpp implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Animal.h"
Animal::Animal(): _name("unknown")
    {
        cout << "constructing Animal object" << endl;
    };
Animal::~Animal()
    {
        cout << "destructing Animal object" << endl;
    }
void Animal::speak()
    {
        cout << "Animal speaks" << endl;
    }
void Animal:: move(){};
```

However, the speak() and move() functions are giving me an error: "no declaration matches Animal::speak()" . If I remove the 'const' at the tail of the declaration, there are no issues in compilation. **How do I correctly implement a const function in a .cpp file?**

Comment: Put the const behind `void Animal::move() const{}` in the implementation

Comment: I assumed the question would be closed. But someone else already put the answer.

Comment: You should think about splitting definitions into cpp files in general, especially for small functions. As long you did not compile with LTO, your code typically will be much less optimized if you don't have implementation in header files!

Comment: BTW, don't write `using namespace std;`, especially in your **header files**. Doing so pollutes the global namespace and may cause naming conflicts in unrelated places. [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1458097)

Comment: @Klaus What do you mean by " splitting definitions into cpp files" ? Do you mean that I should just forgo the header file for small programs like this and do everything in the cpp for optimization?

Comment: No! The opposite! Put everything in the header, especially if the methods are small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to put `const` in the implementation.

Change your code to:

```cpp
void Animal::speak() const
{
    cout << "Animal speaks" << endl;
}
void Animal::move() const {};
```